# Animate height when removing items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a snippet of code that removes divs one by one when a button is clicked. This is now working perfectly.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/8/)

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (++count == 11)
      clearInterval(int);
    $('.mydiv').last().remove();
  }, 300);
  $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```

Currently as the divs are removed the wrapper's height snaps to it's new height. I would like to animate this so it does it slowly.

I added the following `CSS` in  hope it would have the desired effect, but it did not have any effect in this instance.

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.8s;
-moz-transition: height 0.8s;
transition: height 0.8s;
```

Comment: it would work if you slideUp each div https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more generic way:

```
$('.mydiv').last().css('opacity', 0).slideUp(100, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 2):

You can set initial height and refresh this height after row deleted.

https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/12/

```
    $('.mydiv').last().remove();
    if(count % 5 ==0)
    {
        var newHeight=$(".wrapper").height() - 55;
        $(".wrapper").animate({height: newHeight+"px"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript; Before you remove one element, you set the current wrapper height to auto, calculate its height and animate to the new height, after removing it;

```
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
$('.wrapper').css('height', $('.wrapper').height());

$("button").click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (++count == 11) {
      clearInterval(int);
    }
    $('.wrapper').css('height', 'auto');
    $('.mydiv').last().remove();
    $('.wrapper').animate({
      height: $('.wrapper').height()
    }, 300);
  }, 300);
  $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```

I have also updated your fiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/11/

It would be even better if you used a second wrapper around your elements and animate the outer wrapper's height to the inner wrapper's;

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
$('.wrapper').css('height', $('.inner-wrapper').height());

$("button").click(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    if (++count == 11) {
      clearInterval(int);
    }
    $('.mydiv').last().remove();
    $('.wrapper').animate({
      height: $('.inner-wrapper').height()
    }, 300);
  }, 300);
  $("span").text($('.mydiv').length);
});
```

New fiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/uu3egrws/13/